# Returning None in flask, but I don't understand why

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I've been trying to build a web scraper to help me keep up with articles published in my industry.

I'm at my wits end, because when I try to run my code through Flask, I keep getting this error:

TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

Here is the code producing the error:

Doc 1 is blogscraper.py and it reads:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def blog_parser(url) -> 'html':
    import requests
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
    result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return result.content


def html(url) -> 'html':
    website = blog_parser(url)
    html = BeautifulSoup(website, 'html.parser')
    return html

def site_articles(url, element, unique_element) -> 'html':
    sitehtml = html(url)
    article_data = sitehtml.find_all(element, unique_element)
    return article_data

def skillsoft_titles(list_item):
    skillsoft_articles = site_articles('https://www.skillsoft.com/blog', "h1", {"class": "entry-title"})
    entries = skillsoft_articles[list_item]
    title = entries.find('a').get_text()
    return title

def skillsoft_link(list_item):
    skillsoft_articles = site_articles('https://www.skillsoft.com/blog', "h1", {"class": "entry-title"})
    entries = skillsoft_articles[list_item]
    link = entries.find('a').get('href')
    return link

def skillsoft_description(list_item):
    skillsoft_articles = site_articles('https://www.skillsoft.com/blog', "div", {"class": "entry-content"})
    entries = skillsoft_articles[list_item]
    description = entries.select_one("div p:nth-of-type(2)").text
    return description

def opensesame_titles(list_item) -> str:
    opensesame_articles = site_articles('https://www.opensesame.com/site/blog/', "div", {"class": "blog-post-right"})
    entries = opensesame_articles[list_item]
    title = entries.find('a').get_text()
    return title

def opensesame_link(list_item) -> str:
    opensesame_articles = site_articles('https://www.opensesame.com/site/blog/', "div", {"class": "blog-post-right"})
    entries = opensesame_articles[list_item]
    link = entries.find('a').get('href')
    return link

def opensesame_description(list_item):
    opensesame_articles = site_articles('https://www.opensesame.com/site/blog/', "section", {"class": "entry-content"})
    entries = opensesame_articles[list_item]
    description = entries.find('p').text
    return description

def cornerstone_titles(list_item) -> str:
    cornerstone_articles = site_articles('https://www.cornerstoneondemand.com/rework', "h2", {"class": "text-blue"})
    entries = cornerstone_articles[list_item]
    title = entries.find('a').get_text()
    return title

def cornerstone_link(list_item) -> str:
    cornerstone_articles = site_articles('https://www.cornerstoneondemand.com/rework', "h2", {"class": "text-blue"})
    entries = cornerstone_articles[list_item]
    link = entries.find('a').get('href')
    return link

def cornerstone_description(list_item) -> str:
    cornerstone_articles = site_articles('https://www.cornerstoneondemand.com/rework', "div", {"class": "col3-teaser-cont"})
    entries = cornerstone_articles[list_item]
    description = entries.find('p').text
    return description


def print_values(list_item, title_func, link_func, desc_func):
    return (print('Title:', title_func(list_item), '\n' 'Link:', link_func(list_item), '\n' 'Description:', desc_func(list_item)))
```

This works fine on it's own, within pycharm it returns exactly what I want it to.

Doc 2 is my flask doc, and the code is:

```
import blogscraper
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

skillsoft_titles = blogscraper.skillsoft_titles
skillsoft_link = blogscraper.skillsoft_link

skillsoft_description = blogscraper.skillsoft_description

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])



def skillsoft():
    output = blogscraper.print_values(1, skillsoft_titles, skillsoft_link, skillsoft_description)
    return output

skillsoft()

app.debug = True
app.run()
app.run(debug = True)
```

This produces the error. For some reason, this produces a None or no return, which doesn't make sense to me after googling the none returns. Any help on this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `print_values` function returns the result of `print(...)` which is `None`. This is what flask is complaining about.

If you just remove the `print` statement you will return a tuple:
`'Title:', title_func(list_item), ...` is a tuple because several values separated by commas are a tuple in Python.

If your flask function returns a tuple, flask assumes it is a tuple containing certain elements, e.g. (response, status), see [about responses](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#about-responses)

Your function should return e.g. a string, like so:

```python
def print_values(list_item, title_func, link_func, desc_func):
    value = ''.join(('Title: ', title_func(list_item), '<br>\n',
                     'Link: <a href=', link_func(list_item), '>', 
                     link_func(list_item), '</a><br>\n',
                     'Description: ', desc_func(list_item)))
    # print (value)
    return value
```

or a list should also be valid, depending on what you want to achieve.

Note, that it is not a good solution to also print out all the answers to the console, so you might want to remove that print statement after you understood how it all works together...

Answer (score 1):

Your `print_values` function returns the return-value of `print` - which happens to be `None`

```
def print_values(list_item, title_func, link_func, desc_func):
    return (print('Title:', title_func(list_item), '\n' 'Link:', link_func(list_item)
```

You need to change this method to return what you want to return.

Like so:

```
def print_values(list_item, title_func, link_func, desc_func):
    return 'Title:' + title_func(list_item) + '\n' + 'Link:' + link_func(list_item)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That created a new error that said read "TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response tuple. The tuple must have the form (body, status, headers), (body, status), or (body, headers)." I turned that into a variable named output, and returned str(output). Now the output is correct, but isn't formatted exactly as I'd hoped, with proper spacing. However, I am so much happier that it is even marginally functional. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @dsmith1515 The function I put was just an example. It will depend on what you exactly want. Point is: don't return the return-value of `print`. You need to return the body & other parts of the response as the error says.